# wrap code by promises

Tags: javascript, jquery, promise

I use `GSAP` library for animation. I am trying to wrap it by promises:

```
$().promise().then(function() {
     var timeline = new TimelineMax();
    timeline.to( $('.box'), 0.5, {css: {boxShadow: '0 0 40px 40px red'}}, 'box' )
            .to($('.box'), 0.5, {css: {boxShadow: 'none'}}, 'box+=5')

})
.then(console.log(1))
```

But, `console.log` run at start. How to fix it?
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jonobr1/qurtxupb/)

Comment: A tool for creating and composing asynchronous [promises](http://documentup.com/kriskowal/q/) in JavaScript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should use `$.Deferred()` for a promise object.

> jQuery.Deferred()
>
> A constructor function that returns a chainable utility object with
>   methods to register multiple callbacks into callback queues, invoke
>   callback queues, and relay the success or failure state of any
>   synchronous or asynchronous function.

[More](http://jqapi.com/#p=jQuery.Deferred)

```
var dfd = $.Deferred();

var timeline = new TimelineMax();

timeline.to( $('.box'), 0.5, {css: {boxShadow: '0 0 40px 40px red'}}, 'box' )
        .to($('.box'), 0.5, {css: {boxShadow: 'none'}}, 'box+=5');

// When animation ended you should call dfd.resolve()

dfd.done(function() {
    alert("succeeded");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass in a function that does the logging:

```
$().promise().then(function() {
     var timeline = new TimelineMax();
    timeline.to( $('.box'), 0.5, {css: {boxShadow: '0 0 40px 40px red'}}, 'box' )
            .to($('.box'), 0.5, {css: {boxShadow: 'none'}}, 'box+=5')

})
.then(function(){ console.log(1) })
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to do something like

```
var def = $.Deferred(function (def) {
    var timeline = new TimelineMax({
        onComplete: function () {
            //on complete of the animation resolve the promise
            def.resolve();
        }
    });

    //rest of your animation code
})

def.done(function (a) {
    //need to do it in a callback
    console.log(1, a)
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/dm0v8h7j/)